# Convert dictionaries in pandas dataframe to list

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe

```
fruit1                   fruit2
[banana,apple,orange]    [apple,nuts,strawberry]
[apple,mango,grape]      [apple,mango,grape,guava]
```

My code for adding the two additional columns is

```
df["fruits_added"] = df.apply(lambda row: set(row.fruit2) - set(row.fruit1), axis=1)
df["fruits_deleted"] = df.apply(lambda row: set(row.fruit1) - set(row.fruit2), axis=1)
```

My desired output is

```
fruit1                   fruit2                       fruits_added         fruits_deleted
[banana,apple,orange]    [apple,nuts,strawberry]    [strawberry,nuts]     [banana,orange]
[apple,mango,grape]      [apple,mango,grape,guava]    [guava]               []
```

but I am getting dictionaries instead

```
fruit1                   fruit2                       fruits_added         fruits_deleted
[banana,apple,orange]    [apple,nuts,strawberry]      {strawberry,nuts}   {banana,orange}
[apple,mango,grape]      [apple,mango,grape,guava]    {guava}              {}
```

Any input is appreciated

Comment: `list(set(row.fruit2) - set(row.fruit1))`?

Comment: `{foo, bar}` is a [set](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset), not a dictionary. That's what you get when you use `set()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Convert sets to lists:

```
df["fruits_added"] = df.apply(lambda row: list(set(row.fruit2) - set(row.fruit1)), axis=1)
df["fruits_deleted"] = df.apply(lambda row: list(set(row.fruit1) - set(row.fruit2)), axis=1)
```

Alternative solution:

```
zipped = zip(df['fruit1'], df['fruit2'])
df["fruits_added"] = [list(set(y) - set(x)) for x, y in zipped]
df["fruits_deleted"] = [list(set(x) - set(y)) for x, y in zipped]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`np.setdiff1d`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.setdiff1d.html)

```
df['fruits_deleted'] = df.apply(lambda x: np.setdiff1d(x.fruit1, x.fruit2), axis=1)
df['fruits_added'] = df.apply(lambda x: np.setdiff1d(x.fruit2, x.fruit1), axis=1)
```